# Google Authorship - mugshot not showing

Tags: google, google-authorship

I've set up Google+ authorship for my photography blog, and used the Google Structured Data Testing Tool to verify the following:

- Authorship is working
- Authorship email verification is working
- rel=author markup has successfully established authorship for this webpage.
- Publisher markup is verified for this page

Unfortunately my authorship information is not showing in Google search results.

Could it be that the latter on my list above (Publisher markup verification, which is set to use my *business* page as opposed to my personal page) could be causing some form of interference?

It's my understanding that blog posts may only be linked to a Google+ personal profile, not a business page, but that you can set up Publisher markup for a business page.

Comment: Additionally http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Authorship%20is%3aquestion may help. This is a common problem and has been asked time and time again.